# reg expression in objective c fails on new line

Tags: objective-c, regex

I want to remove all script tags from HTML using objective c.

I wrote this reg ex:

```
html1 = [html1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<script.+?</script>" withString:@"xxx" options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive|NSRegularExpressionSearch | NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators range:NSMakeRange (0, [html1 length])];
```

This work on strings with no new lines such as:

```
html1 = @"<script> blah blah </script>";
```

But fails on strings with new lines, such as:

```
html1 = @"<script> blah \n blah </script>";
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

ps I'm aware that this fails on nested script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe those regular expression options (such as `NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators`) are valid for `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:` — AFAIK, `NSRegularExpressionSearch` just gives *basic* regex support. For more advanced regular expressions, you'll want to use the NSRegularExpression class.